# Narration cartoon about a town that has weird paranormal occurrences in it

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

It's a narration cartoon about a town that has weird paranormal occurrences in it.

It focused on different characters from time to time but the main character narrates an intro and the outro in a lessons learned kind of style.

Main character is a short kid with light blue/greenish skin and darker blue hair.(and if I am not mistaking a Hawaiian shirt).

His friends are a yellowish skater with a baseball cap and 3-d glasses and a slender girl with pinkish skin and purple pigtail hair and a large nose.

It is a western animation (set in North America it seems) and aired on FoxKids/Jetix about over decade ago (in the Netherlands).

An example of an episode is when the skater friend of the main character discovers he has a guardian angel who is in love with him, feeling invincible he becomes more and more reckless and the guardian angel becomes more protective restricting his freedom (don't remember how it ended).

It was an okay show, nothing special but it has been bugging me for weeks that I can't remember the name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[Moville Mysteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moville_Mysteries)*

> The series revolves around Mosley "Mo" Moville, a high school student in Ouija Falls, where the supernatural and strange happen almost everyday. Mo loves the supernatural, and loves getting involved with solving the mysteries. Joining him are his friends Mimi and Hitch. Occasionally they are joined by local conspiracy theorist BB. Occasionally the three don't have anything to do with the plot of the story, and instead Mo acts as the narrator.

....

> Tommy "Hitch" Hitchcock: (Voiced by Dan Petroijevic) Mo's best friend who speaks in stereotypical Skater lingo and wears 3D glasses all the time. Hitch isn't too bright and occasionally gets the team into trouble

The guardian angel episode may be the twelfth one, "Crushed By An Angel"

> Hitch gets a guardian angel girlfriend hiding from her ex.

### Opener

Found with a search for *cartoon skater guardian angel "3d glasses*

Comment: THANK YOU! this has been bugging me for weeks! and i could not find it even when searching it with similar search criteria like that haha.

Comment: Google tunes its search results constantly and per user. :) I've been doing this for a while.

Comment: Boots, every search result i did ended me with Martin Mystery. It's kinda similar in name and theme :|

Comment: Incidentally, we've had Martin Mystery come up too. :) https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/217281/23243